# ORM for Database with 1000+ Tables

Tags: .net, database, orm

I'm looking for a solid ORM for .NET that can handle over a 1000 tables and entities. What can you suggest? Any comments would be appreciated, but those from people who have actually dealt with this challenge and a description of how with what they dealt with it would be appreciated even more.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a try [LLBLGen](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx) and [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427(VS.80).aspx), but for the number of tables, the entity class generation will take a while in any ORM...

Comment: With over a thousand tables, and no specific requirement that you have a beautiful and clean (POCO) domain model, it seems that the OP does want simply to codegen thousands of database classes and work with the database at a slightly more abstract level than writing SQL strings.

Answer (score 1):

[NHibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/343.html) is a terrific choice.  Some pointers would include to ensure you fully understand the session life-cycle as well as its lazy-loading techniques for lists and object references.